# Upgraded Ubuntu 22.04 distro and MySQL 5.7 stopped working

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-5.7, ubuntu-22.04

I've recently setup a new laptop with Ubuntu 22.04, and MySQL 5.7 which I needed for work. I did so by adding the MySQL APT repository from the Ubuntu 18.04 which worked well.
Today I needed to also install NodeJS 14+ which is not supported by Ubuntu and for some reason I thought "maybe if I upgrade the distro..."
And now my MySQL is dead. And I can't seem to install any new or old version.
After a lot of tries I decided to uninstall and re-install the whole thing and still failing. Any ideas?
My steps below and outcome below

Remove everything:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-client-* mysql-server* mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.12-1_all.deb
```

Verify options available:

```
sudo apt-cache policy mysql-server
mysql-server:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Version table:
     8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 500
        500 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main i386 Packages
     8.0.28-0ubuntu4 500
        500 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
     5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04 500
        500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic/mysql-5.7 amd64 Packages
```

Installing MySQL

```
sudo apt install -fy mysql-client=5.7* mysql-community-server=5.7* mysql-server=5.7*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Selected version '5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04' (MySQL:repo.mysql.com [amd64]) for 'mysql-client'
Selected version '5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04' (MySQL:repo.mysql.com [amd64]) for 'mysql-community-server'
Selected version '5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04' (MySQL:repo.mysql.com [amd64]) for 'mysql-server'
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libmecab2 libtinfo5 mysql-common mysql-community-client
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libmecab2 libtinfo5 mysql-client mysql-common mysql-community-client mysql-community-server mysql-server
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/55,5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 326 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
(Reading database ... 225302 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-mysql-common_5.8+1.0.8_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.8+1.0.8) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libaio1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../1-libaio1_0.3.112-13build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libaio1:amd64 (0.3.112-13build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libtinfo5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../2-libtinfo5_6.3-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libtinfo5:amd64 (6.3-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-community-client.
Preparing to unpack .../3-mysql-community-client_5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-community-client (5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client.
Preparing to unpack .../4-mysql-client_5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client (5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmecab2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../5-libmecab2_0.996-14build9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmecab2:amd64 (0.996-14build9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-community-server.
Preparing to unpack .../6-mysql-community-server_5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-community-server (5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../7-mysql-server_5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up libmecab2:amd64 (0.996-14build9) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.8+1.0.8) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Setting up libaio1:amd64 (0.3.112-13build1) ...
Setting up libtinfo5:amd64 (6.3-2) ...
Setting up mysql-community-client (5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up mysql-client (5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up mysql-community-server (5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.service → /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service.
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xeu mysql.service" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-09-26 17:18:09 WEST; 7ms ago
    Process: 29152 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 29191 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 208ms
dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-server (--configure):
 installed mysql-community-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-community-server (= 5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04); however:
  Package mysql-community-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-community-server
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

EDIT:

Content of `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

```
2022-09-26T16:38:04.895428Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2022-09-26T16:38:04.896770Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.39) starting as process 1649 ...
2022-09-26T16:38:04.898562Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2022-09-26T16:38:04.898580Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2022-09-26T16:38:04.898582Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-09-26T16:38:04.898585Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2022-09-26T16:38:04.898587Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2022-09-26T16:38:04.898589Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2022-09-26T16:38:04.898737Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-09-26T16:38:04.898794Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2022-09-26T16:38:04.899953Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2022-09-26T16:38:04.904842Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-09-26T16:38:04.906364Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2022-09-26T16:38:04.917258Z 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Table flags are 0 in the data dictionary but the flags in file ./ibdata1 are 0x4000!
2022-09-26 17:38:04 0x7f22d7dd1740  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139787627206464 in file ut0ut.cc line 921
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
16:38:04 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 68197 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x3b)[0x55663844bf8b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x377)[0x556637cd9907]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x42520)[0x7f22d7e18520]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(pthread_kill+0x12c)[0x7f22d7e6ca7c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(raise+0x16)[0x7f22d7e18476]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0xd3)[0x7f22d7dfe7f3]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x6afadc)[0x556637cafadc]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN2ib5fatalD1Ev+0x66)[0x5566387fa4c6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x12a724b)[0x5566388a724b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x12a786d)[0x5566388a786d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z6fil_ioRK9IORequestbRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tmmPvS8_+0x322)[0x5566388b39c2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z13buf_read_pageRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_t+0xdd)[0x5566388663cd]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16buf_page_get_genRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tmP11buf_block_tmPKcmP5mtr_tb+0x465)[0x556638838435]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z31trx_rseg_get_n_undo_tablespacesPm+0x14f)[0x5566387d893f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x119ea48)[0x55663879ea48]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z34innobase_start_or_create_for_mysqlv+0x2e76)[0x5566387a2e06]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x106a8dd)[0x55663866a8dd]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x4f)[0x556637d2e45f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xc1d345)[0x55663821d345]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z40plugin_register_builtin_and_init_core_sePiPPc+0x1e5)[0x556638220865]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x6d3960)[0x556637cd3960]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x79e)[0x556637cd502e]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x29d90)[0x7f22d7dffd90]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x80)[0x7f22d7dffe40]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_start+0x2a)[0x556637cc95ea]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? I'm out of ideas

Comment: Do you realize this effort was attempting to update from 5.7.39 to 8.0.30?  What is your latest available backup?  You will probably need to restore.  View profile for contact info.

Comment: I don't have any backup. In the end I just deleted the data as well when purging and that allowed me to re-install everything.